# How do you map over the values of Zip2?

Tags: swift

I have two arrays like `[1, 2, 3]` and `["a", "b", "c"]` and I want to map over the zipped values `(1, "a")`, `(2, "b")`, and `(3, "c")` using Zip2.

If I do this:

```
let foo = map(Zip2([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]).generate()) { $0.0 }
```

foo has the type `ZipGenerator2<IndexingGenerator<Array<Int>>, IndexingGenerator<Array<String>>>?`.

Is there a way to make that an array?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the question. I see it's been answered already, but if you're just after an Array result why not just do this:  
`let foo = map(Zip2([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"])) { $0.0 }`
Then `foo` is an Array.

Comment: Seems reasonable. Either that's something I didn't try, or the Swift library has improved since I posed this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will get you an array from the return value of Zip2:

```
var myZip = Zip2([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]).generate()
var myZipArray: Array<(Int, String)> = []

while let elem = myZip.next() {
    myZipArray += elem
}

println(myZipArray)    // [(1, a), (2, b), (3, c)]
```

**-- UPDATE: EVEN BETTER! --**

```
let myZip = Zip2([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"])
let myZipArray = Array(myZip)

println(myZipArray)    // [(1, a), (2, b), (3, c)]
```

***-- now for fun --***

I'm going to guess that we can init a new Array with anything that responds to `generate()`  ?

```
println(Array("abcde"))  // [a, b, c, d, e]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that `vals` is the result of `Zip2`, which I'll presume is an array of two tuples.  Like this:

```
let vals = [(1, "a"), (2, "b"), (3, "c")]
```

With that, just invoke the `map()` method on an array.

```
vals.map { $0.0 }
```

For example:

```
> vals.map { $0.1 }
$R16: String[] = size=3 {
  [0] = "a"
  [1] = "b"
  [2] = "c"
}
```

Comment: Zip2 is a struct, and not an array of tuples. :\

Comment: When I use map with a range like `map(0..5) { $0 }` then I get an array by wrapping it like `Array(map(0..5) { $0 })`. I'm looking for the similar transform for the Zip2 generator (I think).

Comment: Then don't use Zip2. :-)  It is clearly a hold-over from the Objective-C days where tuples didn't exist as first-class objects.