# How to "merge" two arrays together? (Concatenate strings item-by-item)

Tags: arrays, swift

Say I have two NSString arrays:

```
var firstName = ["Jack", "Sarah", "John"]
var lastName = ["Smith", "Brown", "Doe"]
```

How can I combine them to form an array that looks like,

```
var contacts = ["Jack Smith", "Sarah Brown", "John Doe"]
```

Comment: The traditional functional-language-ish term for this is "sequence zip", given as `map(zip(sequence1, sequence2), func)` in Swift, which is closely related to the [map higher-order-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29). Some interesting results can be found for such, e.g. http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/06/26/swift-sequences.html , https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/04dbc470e17f67f836a2

Comment: Other interesting reads (from SO): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358089/how-do-you-map-over-the-values-of-zip2 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686647/how-can-i-run-through-three-separate-arrays-in-the-same-for-loop , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28723830/functional-programming-way-of-doing-array-conversion - have fun, and come to the hof side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Zip2` (which creates a sequence of pairs from 
the given arrays) + `map()`:

```
let firstName = ["Jack", "Sarah", "John"]
let lastName = ["Smith", "Brown", "Doe"]

let contacts = map(Zip2(firstName, lastName)) { $0 + " " + $1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate a string in various way, for example :

```
var firstStr = "Hello"
var secondStr = "World"

var aStr = firstStr + " " + secondStr // Hello World
var bStr = "\(firstStr) \(secondStr)" // Hello World
```

In you case you just have to loop for a certain number of time (the length of the array for example, but make sure they both have the same length).

```
var firstName = ["Jack", "Sarah", "John"]
var lastName = ["Smith", "Brown", "Doe"]

var contacts : [String] = []

var len = firstName.count

for index in 0..<len {
    contacts.append("\(firstName[index]) \(lastName[index])")
}
```